# Finding a foldername beginning with "Project" and renaming

Tags: batch-file, tags, character, filenames

I am looking to find a folder and rename it to soemthing differnet. Example: how can I find a folder beginning with the characters "Project" in C:Test\Test2\Project12345 and rename it to C:\Test\Test2\Project1?

Thanks
John.

Comment: At the command prompt: `for /D %a in (C:Test\Test2\Project12345\Project*) do move "%a" C:\Test\Test2\Project1`

Comment: Hi, I've tried to run this code but it doesnt seem to work. Could u tell me what the code is doing?   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Far manager. It will help you find files and folders in a certain directory. Im using it too, and its great.

Go check it out: [Far manager](http://www.farmanager.com/)